# Failed to create sub domain on windows server using Plesk

Tags: windows, iis, plesk

I am using Plesk Obsidian 18.0.36 on windows server 2016. I have deleted a sub domain and then trying to create sub domain again. Its giving error. I have noticed that folder has been created in the directory. but cannot access the sub domain. It came up with following error.

Domain subdomain.domain.com.au creation failed
•   Filename: \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config
•   Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/authorization' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
•
•
•   In module
•   Exception type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
•   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrPath)
•   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
•   at ServerManagerFactory.getAdministrationGlobalSectionInternal(String sectionPath, Type sectionType)
•   at ServerManagerFactory.getManagementAuthorizationSection()
•   at IISWebSite.disableManagement(IISWebSite* )
•
•   at disableManagement()(WebServerAdapter::disableManagement line 2356)
•   at configHosting(subdomain.domain.com.au)(WebServerAdapter::configHosting line 426)
•   at configHosting(subdomain.domain.com.au)(WebServerManager::configHosting line 2822)
•   at Unable to execute console command: '--install-vhost'(vconsoleapp::start line 95)
•   at Unable to execute command: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\admin\bin64\websrvmng" --install-vhost "--vhost-config=C:/Program Files (x86)/Plesk/PrivateTemp/iah82d2d7ed.tmp"'(vconsoleapp::run line 117)
•   (Error code 1)

Comment: The error message clearly tells you that there is a problem with the content of the `system.webServer/management/authorization` part, so please check it in the web.config.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have no clue where this web.config file is. Any hint please

Comment: It should be administration.config, and its location is `Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config`

Comment: i have checked it. there are two files in this location applicationHost.config and redirection.config but no adminsitration.config

Comment: i have figured out that administration.config file was deleted. i have no clue how but was deleted.

Comment: If you want to restore the administration.config file, you can try to uninstall IIS, reboot system, reinstall IIS should be able restore config files.